# How to update tinymce data from database using laravel

Tags: javascript, mysql, laravel-5, tinymce

I'm having a trouble here guys hope you can help me.

The tinymce works absolutely fine when saving it to the database, the problem is when i try to retrieve it i using this `{!!  !!}` nothing shows. how can i print the data from the database back to `textarea` tag of tinymce the way i design it so that i can redesign it again and again.

edit.blade.php:

```
<li class="step">
            <div data-step-label="Lesson Layout" class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">Step 2</div>
            <div class="step-content lesson-editor">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col s12">
                 <textarea id="mytextarea editor" name="editor" rows="8" cols="80" value="{{ $lessons->editor }}"></textarea>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="step-actions">
               <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn blue next-step" >CONTINUE</button>
               <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn-flat previous-step">BACK</button>
             </div>
            </div>
          </li>
```

tinymce script:

```
selector: "textarea",
      height: '350px',
      plugins: [
          "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
          "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
          "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
          "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
      ],
```

pardon me for my bad english.
thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

remember to use :

```
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data.definition);
```

where `definition` is the name of your column where you store your `Tinymce` value , and i used `data` because i'm using `ajax` , you just need to insert the tinymce column name in the brackets .

for example here is my code written with ajax :

```
    $('body').delegate('#content-info #edit','click',function (e) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.get("{{ URL::to('content/edit') }}",{id:id},function (data) {

            $('#frm-updatecontentform').find('#id').val(data.id);
            $('#frm-updatecontentform').find('#titlee').val(data.title);
            $('#frm-updatecontentform').find('#brieff').val(data.brief);
            $('#frm-updatecontentform').find('#inputatt').val(data.input_at);
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(data.definition);
            $('#frm-updatecontentform').find('#page_addresss').val(data.page_address);
            $('#frm-updatecontentform').find('#start_datee').val(data.Begin_at);
            $('#frm-updatecontentform').find('#end_datee').val(data.End_at);

        });
    });
```

this is the `tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(tinymceColumnname);` you have to pay attention to .